# View Compatible with IOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios

I want to a create a subview In IOS that will autosizing according to parent View. But I want Subview Height must be fixed when my IPhone Rotate to landscape mode. Also allow scrollView to show full content of subview. This parent view compatible IOS 7 and IOS 8.

Comment: Have you thought about use size classes? This could make it a lot easier to set constraints for certain screen sizes / orientations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Xcode and set the Height Constraint that you want.

Set leading trailing top and bottom Space Constraint to 0.